# Как исправить переключение раскладки клавиатуры в Debian LXDE?

Tags: debian, клавиатура, lxde

Debian c LXDE. При установке системы выбирал `ru`,`en` и `alt+shift`.  Когда система стартанула `alt+shift` не работал. Принудительно изменил в параметрах на `альт + шифт` долго не хотело работать, потом понял, когда мышкой на панели переключаешь на `ru`, `альт+шифт` работает, но когда стоит `en` не работает. И при этом значок раскладки не меняется. Как исправить что бы с `en` переключалось на `ru` и обратно и желательно что бы значек на панели менялся?

Comment: На LXDE смогу посмотреть только вечером на сервере, а на Xfce уже могу сказать. В меню, найди *Keyboard* (у меня все на инглише), далее там пару пунктов должно быть (табов), переключи на последний, там где *Layout*, далее добавляешь необходимые языки и в окошке *Change layout options* устанавливаешь нужную комбинацию для смены языка. Всё вроде просто. Думаю, в LXDE как то так же

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему убрав IBus с панели, там надо в настройках галочку снять "отображать на панели" и поставил стандартный `Обработчик раскладки клавиатуры` все заработало, но теперь стала новая проблема с copy-paste через Ctrl+C/V но это уже совсем другая история.